I need to access the model in sagemakers default_input_fn?
Sagemaker model hosting uses default_input_fn for input transformations. However, in this function I need access to the output of default_model_fn, which is only passed to default_predict_fn.
What is the best way to access the model output from default_model_fn? Using a global variable, or?
